# Orientation problem

Tags: android

We handling Landscape and portrait in iphone and android

```
window.onorientationchange = function() {
if(window.orientation == 0)
{
//Loading portrait content and hiding landscape content
}
else if(window.orientation == -90 || window.orientation == 90)
{
//Loading Landscape content and hiding portrait content
}
};
```

Problem is while rotating its taking time to Loading content

Can anyone help me out to fix this issue.

Comment: Have you added android:configChanges="orientation" to your AndroidManifest?

Comment: Add more detail. What is your problem, is it taking too much time to rotate, to load content?

Comment: That doesn't look like standard android APIs, are you using some cross-phone toolkit or something? You have to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you could improve performance by using the Android API instead of your own functions for hiding and loading content when the user rotates the screen.  If you don't lock orientation, then when the user rotates their phone your Activity will be destroyed and created again in the new orientation.

If you want to load different resources in landscape and portrait mode, like a layout (although it could be anything in your res/ folder), then put the pertinent resource files in res/layout-land and res/layout-port under the same filename.  Android will load resources from the correct folder automatically.  Of course, you should make a habit of providing default resources whenever you make resources for a specific state.  If you want portrait to be your default orientation, then put those resources in res/layout and put your landscape resources in res/layout-land.  No res/layout-port folder needed.

See here for full documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources